# Detail instructions on manually updating message templates (5.9.0 to 5.10.4)

Tags: upgrade, message-templates

We just updated our CiviCRM (Wordpress) from 5.9.0 to 5.10.4. Prior to the associated database upgrade, I got this message about having to upgrade our customized message templates. I screen copied the text but don't have the link to the "detailed instructions."

Any idea on where I would find those instructions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It links to an old wiki page that redirects to https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/message-templates

Note it doesn't tell you what your customizations were before. You would need to know that separately or look at a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to figure out what changes you made to the original template, and then apply those to the updated template.  A tool like [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) is useful to look at the differences and copy them.  If you plan on changing these in the future, keeping a record of your changes in git also helps.